# BigQueryInsertJobOperator with Export Configuration

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to retrieve GA data from BigQuery using the operators provided in the airflow documentation.

The documentation is not very explicit concerning the usage of the BigQueryInsertJobOperator which is replacing BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator.

My Dag work as follow:

1. In a Dataset List the table names
2. Using BigQueryInsertJobOperator query all the table using this syntax from the [cookbook](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089#specific):

```
 `{my-project}.{my-dataset}.events_*`
 WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '{start}' AND '{end}'
```

```
select_query_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="select_query_job",
    gcp_conn_id='big_query',
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": build_query.output,
            "useLegacySql": False,
            "allowLargeResults": True,
            "useQueryCache": True,
        }
    }
)
```

3. Retrieve the job id from the Xcom and use BigQueryInsertJobOperator with extract in the configuration to get query results, like in this [api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults)

However, I receive an error message and I am unable to access the data. All the steps before step 3 are working perfectly, I can see it from the cloud console.
The Operator I tried:

```
retrieve_job_data = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="get_job_data",
    gcp_conn_id='big_query',
    job_id=select_query_job.output,
    project_id=project_name,
    configuration={
        "extract": {
        }
    }
)

#Or

retrieve_job_data = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="get_job_data",
    gcp_conn_id='big_query',
    configuration={
        "extract": {
            "jobId": select_query_job.output,
            "projectId": project_name
        }
    }
)
```

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{my-project}/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Required parameter is missing
[2022-08-16, 09:44:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1415} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=BIG_QUERY, task_id=get_job_data, execution_date=20220816T054346, start_date=20220816T054358, end_date=20220816T054401
[2022-08-16, 09:44:01 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 628 for task get_job_data (400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{my-project}/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Required parameter is missing; 100144)
```

Following the above link gives:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.ListJobs"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I see that the error is http 401, and I don't have access to gc, which is not normal since my gcp_conn_id works in the other operators (and specifying the project Id!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `ExtractJob` type, you must pass a `destinationUri` or `destinationUris` and `sourceTable`.
This explains the 401 `Required parameter is missing` error message.

Now that you have a `job_id`, you can implement a `pre_execute` hook in your constructor to fetch the job.

The `destinationTable` field in the job configuration is needed to configure the `Extract` job. Even though you have configured the `Query` job to `useQueryCache`, Bigquery will store the results in anonymised table.

The configuration for the `Query` job when it is retrieved looks like:

```
{
  /*...*/
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "SELECT weight_pounds, state, year, gestation_weeks FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.natality] ORDER BY weight_pounds DESC LIMIT 10;",
      "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "redacted",
        "datasetId": "_redacted",
        "tableId": "anon0d85adcadde61fa17550f9841810e343fb5bc82d"
      },
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
      "priority": "INTERACTIVE",
      "useQueryCache": true,
      "useLegacySql": true
    },
    "jobType": "QUERY"
  },
  /*...*/
}
```

```py
retrieve_job_data = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="get_job_data",
    gcp_conn_id='big_query',
    job_id=select_query_job.output,
    project_id=project_name,
    pre_execute=populate_extract_source_table
    configuration={
        "extract": {
           "destinationUris": ["gs://your-bucket/some-path"]
        }
    }
)
```

```py
def populate_extract_source_table(ctx):
    job_id = ctx['task'].job_id # the job id of the query job
    task = ctx['task']
    hook = BigQueryHook(
            gcp_conn_id=task.gcp_conn_id,
            delegate_to=task.delegate_to,
            impersonation_chain=task.impersonation_chain,
        )
    # Retreive job
    job = hook.get_job(
                project_id=task.project_id,
                location=task.location,
                job_id=job_id,
            )
    # Set the sourceTable for the extract insert job to that for the query insert job.
    jr = job.to_api_repr()
    dag.configuration['extract']['sourceTable'] = jr["configuration"]["query"]["destinationTable"]
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I don't know where to find  a "destinationUris"... I want to store the result locally and not in the gcs, do you know how can I do this?

Comment: `destinationUris` is a google cloud bucket location. If you want to store the result locally, you should define the `get_job_data` operation as a `PythonOperator` and not `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`. In the callback for the `PythonOperator`, retrieve the job and invoke the [result](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.17.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.result) method paging through the data and writing each page to your desired location.

Comment: You could retrieve the query results from the `job` as a [`dataframe`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.17.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.to_dataframe) and use the [`dataframe.to_*`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) APIs to write the results in your desired location.

Comment: I tried using the ```BigQueryGetDataOperator``` with the temporary table infos from ```populate_extract_source_table```, however, the result is an empty list. Do you know why?

Comment: When using `BigQueryGetDataOperator`, you need to be setting [`dataset_id` and `table_id`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery.py#L443-L444). How are you setting the value for those attributes?

Comment: yes I copied both from ```jr["configuration"]["query"]["destinationTable"]```, And it run successfully but return an empty list.

Comment: Nevermind I made a mistake in my query. Your option using the ```result``` method and mine with ```BigQueryGetDataOperator``` works. Thanks for everything I couldn't do it without you

Comment: Glad that you figured it out in the end! 